# What kind of MongoDB query finds same value multiple times in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have documents like this in a MongoDB

```
{
    "mylist":[
        {"value": 1},
        {"value": 2},
        {"value": 3}
    ]
},
{
    "mylist":[
        {"value": 1},
        {"value": 2},
        {"value": 1}
    ]
}
```

How can I query the documents that have `{"value": 1}` multiple times (ie. the latter) in the list?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for aggregation pipeline treatment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB - How to find all objects within an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397737/mongodb-how-to-find-all-objects-within-an-array)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Actually not a good candiate currently at all. The best you can do without altering things is `$unwind` and `$project`. Which is not a good solution. Will get better in the next MongoDB release though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably best handled with a JavaScript evaluation using [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```js
db.colletion.find({
    "$where": function() {
        return this.mylist.filter(function(el) {
            return el.value == 1;
        }).length >= 1;
    }
})
```

Or currently not so greatly handled in aggregation:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "if": { "$eq": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$value", 1 ] }, 1 },
        "then": "$$DESCEND",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "if": { "$gt": [{ "$size": "$mylist" }, 1 ] },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }}
])
```

Or better handled in the future with `$filter`:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": {
        "if": {
            "$gt": [
                { "$size": { "$filter": {
                    "input": "$mylist",
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": {
                        "$eq": [ "$$el.value", 1 ]
                    }
                }}},
                1
            ]
        },
        "then": "$$KEEP",
        "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }}
])
```

Where that latter operator is not available yet until the next release of MongoDB. But in general you want to be able to filter out and "count" the occurences of matches. These are a couple of ways to do this.

Comment: How efficient is the $where statement in comparison with using a bit more complex aggregation command like the latter ones are?
The first one is by far clearest in terms of readability at least.

Comment: @user541905 The main thing to understand about aggregation pipelines is that in most cases ( this is one of them ) each pipeline stage represents a pass through all of the data in the collection, or at least those documents remaining after processing a stage. So as stated, the best that can presently be produced is two passes, and that is likely to add time. That said, MongoDB 3.2 is in release candidate stage as of writing so the last would be most efficient when released. The `$where` should be the current fastest way. But you should really always test and benchmark on your own data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aggregation pipeline - I'd suggest unwinding the arrays, then grouping by original document and value, then filtering to only leave those results that have a count greater than 1.